# Plotting time-series data in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, interpolation, time

I'm attempting to produce interpolated plots of water quality time-series data from ArcSDE.   This is the data format:

```
OID    WELL_ID  WELL_NAME  SAMPLE_ID  SAMPLE_DAT    PARAM   RESULT

90-------1---------WELL A-----19-24231----5/4/1966----CHLORIDE--------130

91-------1---------Well A-----19-24295------7/7/1966----CHLORIDE--------130

92-------2---------Well B-----19-24478----1/6/1967-----CHLORIDE---------122

93-------3---------Well C-----19-24597----5/5/1967-----CHLORIDE----------115
```

and onward for thousands of records.  Each well has many records, and the sampling is erratic, some not being sampled for years.   I've tried a few things, but I want to see if anyone else has encountered something similar and how they approached it.

Comment: are you having any particular problems with this?

Comment: Nevermind.  I realize there's not good enough spatial resolution to make the interpolation significant.  I was trying to develop a streamlined process for querying the table from sde and developing interpolated rasters and time-series animations...